# How to reassign previous Bitlocker encryption to new system disk

Tags: automation, bitlocker, disk-encryption

My previous PC had 2 disks and both were Bitlocker encrypted with password. I remember vaguely that I could configure it in a way that the second disk will be unlocked when the first disk got unlocked (which was system).

I have now a new PC with a new system disk (currently not encrypted) and additionally those two previous disks. I want to enable Bitlocker in the similar fashion: Unlocking the now new system disk should also unlock the other two disks.

Right now I don't get such option when trying to setup Bitlocker on the new system disk.

How do I need to configure the new system disk and/or those two previous disks so I can relink the automatic unlocking?

[image: current situation]

Comment: You probably will have to disable (not suspend) BitLocker protection and the enable it to accomplish what you want. Those disks appear to be locked. If you right click on the disk what are the options? Provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Preamble: My new PC has a fully fledged TPM so I had to forcefully enable PIN/Password method, best described in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1217390/118136 (*But this is just a personal choice on how I like to use Bitlocker, your case may vary and you may want to fully use the TPM*)

1. Open `Manage Bitlocker` in Settings (use the search). The current situation probably looks similar to this (ignore the warning as it is related to the preamble above which edited system policies to allow password method):
   [image: current situation]
2. Enable Bitlocker on your system drive as you usually would do
3. Press `Turn on auto-unlock` on the other drives

That's it, it should look like this and reboot to test it out:
[image: final situation]