Drive does not have an associated BitLocker volume
I'm going through enabling bitlocker for all drives on my desktop (Windows 10 22H2 19045.4894).
I've successfully enabled bitlocker for my system volume C (NVME, with password protection according to https://superuser.com/a/1217390/2761) and one other partition on a separate harddrive.
Now I'm trying to enable it for other (older) partitions and some of them fail.
When I run
Enable-BitLocker D: -PasswordProtector
I'm getting
Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal : D: does not have an associated BitLocker volume.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1:344 char:35
+ ... bleVolume = Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal -MountPoint $MountPoin ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal

Or when I run
manage-bde -on D: -pw
I'm getting
ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070057):
The parameter is incorrect.

and there's no option to enable it on the UI as well.
It works for one of the partitions though which is on the same drive with a failing partition.
I've compared the NTFS version between the failing and successful partitions and it's the same.
How do I enable BitLocker on the failing NTFS partitions?

By… enabling BitLocker? Add-BitLockerKeyProtector can only be used after BitLocker has been enabled on a volume. It does not enable BitLocker itself to encrypt the volume. Did you do that yet?

@DanielB, I did try other commands, Enable-Bitlocker, bde-edit -on, same result, My theory now is that it might be because the partitions once were windows partitions, will check today

You should elaborate in your question. The relevant PowerShell cmdlet is Enable-BitLocker, the equivalent command is manage-bde -on. Please provide the exact command line you used and what the result was.

@DanielB, updated

Are you sure the command manage-bde -on D: -pw is correct? According to the manage-bde help page there is no -pw argument on Windows 10.

@Robert, yes, just tested again, the -pw option is recognized by manage-bde version 10.0.19041 on my Windows 10

The issue was the partitions where it failed to enable BitLocker were marked as Active (from old windows installs back when the drives where my primary drive).
Removing the Active flag and rebooting fixed the issue.
In order to remove the Active flag instructions from this answer can be used.
When BitLocker sees an Active partition it thinks it's an OS partition and looks for a (separate) BitLocker volume (to boot Windows from before the main system volume is decrypted).
